# how to convert result of an select sql query into a new table in ms access

Tags: sql, ms-access

how to convert result of an select sql query into a new table in msaccess ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use sub queries

```
SELECT a,b,c INTO NewTable 
FROM (SELECT a,b,c
FROM TheTable
WHERE a Is Null)
```

Comment: Why use a subquery? i.e. why not add the INTO into the inner query?

Comment: Note the resulting 'table' will not have a key, therefore is not a table at all.

Answer (score 9):

Like so:

```
SELECT    *
INTO      NewTable
FROM      OldTable
```

Comment: Not sure Access will actually *replace* `NewTable` in that situation, it may actually append stuff to the table instead, which then would fully match the user's request as I understand it.

Comment: @Romain Muller: Why don't you fire up Access and find out the answer to your question, instead of muttering out loud about it?

Comment: In point of fact, if you run that SQL in the Access QBE, it will ask you if you want to replace the existing table. If you run it with DoCmd.RunSQL with SetWarnings ON, it will also prompt you. If you attempt to execute it in DAO, it will fail because the table already exists. In no case will it append the records to an existing table.

Answer (score 3):

First, create a table with the required keys, constraints, domain checking, references, etc. Then use an `INSERT INTO..SELECT` construct to populate it.

Do not be tempted by `SELECT..INTO..FROM` constructs. The resulting table will have no keys, therefore will not actually be a table at all. Better to start with a proper table then add the data e.g. it will be easier to trap bad data.

For an example of how things can go wrong with an `SELECT..INTO` clause: it can result in a column that includes the NULL value and while after the event you can change the column to NOT NULL the engine will not replace the `NULLs`, therefore you will end up with a NOT NULL column containing `NULL`s!

Also consider creating a 'viewed' table e.g. using `CREATE VIEW` SQL DDL rather than a base table.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it through the user interface, you can also:

A) Create and test the select query. Save it.

B) Create a make table query. When asked what tables to show, select the query tab and your saved query.

C) Tell it the name of the table you want to create.

D) Go make coffee (depending on taste and size of table)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select *
Into newtable
From somequery
```