# Copy rows from source table to new table given condition

Tags: sql, ms-access

I use the following code but the program gives out an error and does not work:

```
INSERT INTO dest
SELECT *
FROM source
WHERE source.var="value";
```

I want to copy all rows and columns from the source table into the destination table given a condition. How do I solve this?

Comment: What is the exact error message that you get? Are table schemas for `dest` and `source` **absolutely** identical (including order of columns, their names and types)?

Comment: @peterm, actually I just created `dest` without any content thinking that by using `SELECT *` every row that fulfills the condition is copied. Is that wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query using [SELECT INTO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208934%28v=office.12%29.aspx). It will create new table and add rows to it.

```
SELECT *
INTO dest
FROM source
WHERE source.var="value";
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839453/how-to-convert-result-of-an-select-sql-query-into-a-new-table-in-ms-access