# MS Access: Syntax error in CREATE TABLE statement

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am running this SQL query in MS Access:

```
 CREATE TABLE EX_P_TEMP
 AS (SELECT 
         EXPORT_POSTING_ID, IMPORT_POSTING_ID, DIS, 
         MILE_SAVED, IMPORT_AVAILABLE 
     FROM POTENTIAL_PAIRS);
```

Error:

> Syntax error in CREATE TABLE statement.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to convert result of an select sql query into a new table in ms access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839453/how-to-convert-result-of-an-select-sql-query-into-a-new-table-in-ms-access)

Comment: May I know why my question is still down-voted?

Comment: The question as it stands is not really helpful to other stackexchange users as it is a duplicate of another question elsewhere..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't look like valid Access syntax.  If you are trying to create a new table based on the results of a `SELECT`, try this intead:

```
SELECT EXPORT_POSTING_ID, IMPORT_POSTING_ID, DIS, MILE_SAVED, IMPORT_AVAILABLE
INTO EX_P_TEMP
FROM POTENTIAL_PAIRS;
```

Comment: It worked but it didn't copy column entries from old to new table. How do I copy them?

Comment: It should have copied over the values.  That's the whole point of this statement.  Can you double check?

Comment: See [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208934(v=office.12).aspx) for how it should work.

Comment: I checked. When I run the query it asks: Enter parameter Value for all of the copied columns.

Comment: What query?  Try opening the table directly.  The data should be there

Comment: The one you posted above. The table is blank.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82383/discussion-between-sstan-and-karvy1).